# One karate report for all tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, karate

I'm running 2 separate tests each of which with its feature files (suppose I have another `run2()` method with the same settings except `"features-dir"`):

```
@Test
fun run1() {
    val reportDir = "build/report-dir"
    val results: Results = Runner
        .path("features-dir")
        .debugMode(true)
        .outputCucumberJson(true)
        .reportDir(reportDir)
         ....
        .parallel(1)
}
```

When I run all the test (`run1()` and `run2()`) I get the report of the last run only, the first one is lost due to overwrite. What I need is to have one report with the information (features) of two runs. Is that possible?